# Generate Gradient Colors for Nodes in Sankey Charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm working with a Sankey chart in javascript (in a react app if that matters), and would like the nodes in Sankey to have a gradient based on their x, y coordinates.

For example, in a diagram like below where x-axis goes to right and y-axis goes down, I'd like to specify a starting color at the origin, and possible a stopping color at max x value and a stopping color at max y value, and have a way to generate a color for each point in the plane given an (x, y) pair.

```
(origin)
|-------> x coordinate
|
|
v
y coordinate
```

So is there a gradient formula (`get_gradient`) that can be used in the Sankey in the following way?

```
node.append("rect")
  .style("fill", function (d) {
    return get_gradient(d.x, d.y);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/gcbojt2p/1/

The idea is to create 2 color interpolators for x/y. Then, given an x/y pair, convert it to normalized numbers based on the svg width/height. So if x is 500, and the width is 1000, the normalized x is 0.5. Then you can plug that into the interpolater to generate a color. Do the same for the y, and now you have 2 colors to make the gradient.

```
var y = d3.interpolate('#fff','#2196f3')
var x = d3.interpolate('#fff','#4caf50')

var width = 400;
var height=  400;

d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width',width)
    .attr('height',height)
    .on('mousemove',function(){
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this)
        var xNormalized = mouse[0]/width
        var yNormalized = mouse[1]/height

        var xColor = x(xNormalized)
        var yColor = y(yNormalized)

        var gradient = `linear-gradient(${xColor},${yColor})`
        d3.select('div').style('background',gradient)
    })
```